# for python 3.7.6 which myql-client version is supported

Tags: python, mysql-python

for python 3.7.4 the myqli client library is supported which is given below

```
mysqlclient-1.4.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```

but i have python 3.7.6 which mysql-client wheel is supported 
Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Does that one not do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a good idea to use a package manager handle versioning instead of doing it manually. If you do that, then you can just ask the package manager what version it installed. For example, for your python 3.7.6 (and on Windows... slightly different on linux):

```
python -m venv my_env 
my_env\Scripts\activate.bat 
python -m pip install --upgrade pip 
pip install mysqlclient
pip list
```

That last `pip list` will return the list of libraries you have in that environment, and what version each one has.

Answer (score 0):

This one will work for all python 3.7.x versions if you want version 1.4.4 of the package.
However there is newer version - 1.4.6 and you should use it, unless there is reason to stick to 1.4.4

Alternatively you may look at [mysql-connector-python](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/)
The docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/